# Java REST Web Service with internal threading mechanism

Tags: java, resteasy

I have a data-push web service implemented in REST which pushes the data in database.

Now I want to create one more web service which will take input from a data-push web service and perform some business logic for any alerts. If any alert is present then it will call an alert service. In this case data-push web service should detach as soon as it posts the required data.

My doubt is if there are too many request on data-push web service - lets say for every second - then how will it handle threading mechanism and post on new web service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the throughput of the service pushing data, you can queue the data push requests up and have a pool of worker threads process them as time and system resources permit.

The queuing mechanism could be any number of solutions depending on your scalability and throughput requirements:

1. In-Memory
2. JMS Messaging Middleware
3. Relational Database
4. Distributed Cache